# Publishing PostGIS Rasters in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, postgresql, postgis-2.0

**How do I publish PostGIS rasters using GeoServer?**

I have spent a lot of time trying to create a Raster datasource using Image Mosaic JDBC but with no luck.

Steps performed:
 
1. Downloaded and Installed the JDBC Image Mosaic extension (worked ok)
2. Created the "Connection Parameter" files:

*connect.postgis.xml.inc:*

```
<connect>
  <dstype value="DBCP"/>
  <username value="postgres" />
  <password value="password" />
  <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/db1" />
  <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <maxActive value="10"/>
  <maxIdle value="0"/>
</connect>
```

*mapping.postgis.xml.inc:*

```
<spatialExtension name="postgis"/>
<mapping>
    <masterTable name="mosaic" >
        <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
        <maxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
        <maxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
        <minXAttribute name="minX"/>
        <minYAttribute name="minY"/>
        <resXAttribute name="resX"/>
        <resYAttribute name="resY"/>
        <tileTableNameAtribute name="tiletable" />
    </masterTable>
    <tileTable>
        <blobAttributeName name="rast" />
    </tileTable>
</mapping>
```

*osm.postgis.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
  <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.postgis.xml.inc">
  <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.postgis.xml.inc">]>
<config version="1.0">
  <coverageName name="gfm"/>
  <coordsys name="EPSG:25832"/>
  <!-- interpolation 1 = nearest neighbour, 2 = bilinear, 3 = bicubic -->
  <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
  <verify cardinality="false"/>
  &mapping;
  &connect;
</config>
```

where "mosaic" is a table (columns: name, titletable,minX,minY,maxX,maxY,resX,resY) containing one row: "gfm, testrastertable, , , , , , ,"

 3. Saved the config files in ../geoserver/data_dir/coverages/

 4. While trying to add an Image Mosaic JDBC data store I receive the following error:

```
Error: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Unable to acquire a reader for this coverage with format: ImageMosaicJDBC
```

Update: Geoserver log

```
2012-10-24 14:09:11,404 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 14 locking in mode WRITE
2012-10-24 14:09:11,404 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 14 got the lock in mode WRITE
2012-10-24 14:09:11,406 DEBUG [geoserver.config] - Persisting coverage store raster_store
2012-10-24 14:09:11,408 DEBUG [geoserver.config] - Persisted org.geoserver.catalog.impl.CoverageStoreInfoImpl to /opt/geoserver/data_dir/workspaces/raster/raster_store/coveragestore.xml
2012-10-24 14:09:11,416 DEBUG [geoserver.config] - Persisted $Proxy15 to /opt/geoserver/data_dir/global.xml
2012-10-24 14:09:11,438 ERROR [imagemosaic.jdbc] - 
2012-10-24 14:09:11,438 WARN [imagemosaic.jdbc] - 
java.io.IOException
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCReader.<init>(ImageMosaicJDBCReader.java:163)
    at org.geotools.gce.imagemosaic.jdbc.ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.getReader(ImageMosaicJDBCFormat.java:209)
....
2012-10-24 14:09:11,439 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:coverages/osm.postgis.xml
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Unable to acquire a reader for this coverage with format: ImageMosaicJDBC
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:115)
...
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Unable to acquire a reader for this coverage with format: ImageMosaicJDBC
    at org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogBuilder.buildCoverage(CatalogBuilder.java:812)
    at org.geoserver.web.data.layer.NewLayerPageProvider.getItems(NewLayerPageProvider.java:82)
    ... 95 more
2012-10-24 14:09:11,441 DEBUG [geoserver.config] - Removing coverage store raster_store
2012-10-24 14:09:11,446 DEBUG [geoserver.config] - Persisted $Proxy15 to /opt/geoserver/data_dir/global.xml
2012-10-24 14:09:11,459 DEBUG [org.geoserver] - Thread 14 releasing the lock in mode WRITE
```

Comment: turn logging up to verbose and check the log file

Comment: just updated with the log...doesn't tell me too much

Comment: As no-one here seems able to help, you could try the GeoServer mailing list: http://geoserver.org/display/GEOS/Mailing+Lists

Comment: Any update on this question?

Comment: No updates... I had to drop the idea of creating a JDBC Image Mosaic because i just couldn't create it in Geoserver. I am using now the ImagePyramid store and files are kept on the disk.

Answer (score 8):

I worked through several issues trying to use a postgis raster in geoserver similar to the OP. The below is how I successfully loaded my raster data.

Preconfiguration:  A BNG geotiff layer, generated from FME, has been imported into postgis using `raster2pgsql`. The command used was:

```
raster2pgsql -s 27700 -I -M -C {geotiffName}.tif -t 100x100 -l 2,4,6 {schema}.{tableName} | psql -U {user} -d {database}
```

This created the raster table along with its pyramid tables.

Currently my server has an instance of `Geoserver 2.6.2`. To use Postgis rasters it requires the extension JDBC Image Mosaic which can be downloaded from http://geoserver.org/release/2.6.2/

The extension .jar was then extracted into `WEB-INF/lib`. This will then enable geoserver to use rasters from postgis.  However to access the data several settings need configuring.

Following the instructions in: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html but slightly tweaked:

```
create table {schema}.MOSAIC (NAME varchar(254) not null,
     TileTable varchar(254)not null,
     minX FLOAT8,minY FLOAT8, maxX FLOAT8, maxY FLOAT8,resX FLOAT8, resY FLOAT8, primary key (NAME,TileTable))
```

Now insert records for a "coverage", named oek in the example, these are your raster tables: the master one and pyramid ones.

```
insert into {schema}.MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', {Main raster table name});
insert into {schema}.MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', {raster pyramid 2 table name});
insert into {schema}.MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', {raster pyramid 4 table name});
insert into {schema}.MOSAIC (name, tiletable) values ('oek', {raster pyramid 6 table name});
```

Also according to the docs, for Postgis JDBC drivers < version 9 it is necessary to set a property in the database:

```
ALTER DATABASE dbname SET bytea_output TO 'escape'
```

Now Geoserver configuration:

Within your Geoserver data directory create a directory `/data/coverages`, this needs to contain 3 files: `connect.pgraster.xml.inc, mapping.pgraster.xml.inc, oek.pgraster.xml`

Follow http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html for their naming and contents.  Obviously adjust the database connection string and username/password settings in `connect.pgraster.xml.inc`

`mapping.pgraster.xml.inc` is where we need to reference the raster tables correctly.

```
<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
 <mapping>
  <masterTable name="MOSAIC" >
          <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
          <maxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
          <maxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
          <minXAttribute name="minX"/>
          <minYAttribute name="minY"/>
          <resXAttribute name="resX"/>
          <resYAttribute name="resY"/>
          <tileTableNameAtribute  name="tiletable" />
  </masterTable>
  <tileTable>
          <blobAttributeName name="rast" />
  </tileTable>
</mapping>
```

So this will get the values we added to the MOSAIC table, the `name` values are the columns of `MOSAIC`, which link to our raster table and pyramid tables.  `rast` is the name of the raster column in the raster tables.

In `oek.pgraster.xml` make sure your SRS is correctly set, 27700 BNG in this case.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
  <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc">
  <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.pgraster.xml.inc">
]>

<config version="1.0">
  <coverageName name="oek"/>
  <coordsys name="EPSG:27700"/>
  <!-- interpolation 1 = nearest neighbour, 2 = bipolar, 3 = bicubic -->
  <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
<axisOrder ignore="false"/>
  &mapping;
  &connect;
</config
```

In Geoserver we can now add a new datastore.

Go to new Add new store.

Select ImageMosaicJDBC

Give it a name and the set the URL to `file:coverages/oek.pgraster.xml`

Save this, and fingers crossed no errors are returned. If they are, check geoserver logs which hopefully will indicate what the issue was, hopefully just a typo or naming issue.

Go to add a new layer and select the new raster data store.

Select your new layer/coverage named oek and publish it.

Then in the layer settings adjust your coordinate system and bounding boxes appropriately.

To style the raster follow docs here: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/sld-reference/rastersymbolizer.html

I added a style:

```
<RasterSymbolizer>
 <Opacity>1.0</Opacity>
  <ColorMap>
   <ColorMapEntry color="#ffffff" quantity="1" label="label1" opacity="1"/>
   <ColorMapEntry color="#0000ff" quantity="200" label="label2" opacity="1"/>
  </ColorMap>
</RasterSymbolizer>
```

This colored my rasters blue where they had a value.

You should then have a usable layer.

Disclaimer: I am no GIS expert, and a lot of what i worked through was trial and error.  I have no doubt that there are better ways to do it, but for the time being I'm only working on a proof of concept to confirm if we have the capability to use raster data in postgis. Finer details like raster values and styling are things I still need to iron out. If I make any further progress I will update my answer.

Comment: I want to publish PostGIS rasters using GeoServer, but the URL's as given in documentation as well as here are not working https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/postgisraster.html http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html

Answer (score 3):

Following the [configuration instructions](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html)  for the PostGIS raster plugin, you should try replacing

```
<spatialExtension name="postgis"/>
```

with

```
<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
```

in configration file `mapping.postgis.xml.inc`.

Answer (score 0):

After several tryes, noticed that
GDAL plugin in GeoServer must be installed for  ImageMosaicJDBC to work.