# Problem in importing raster data from PostGIS to Geoserver

Tags: postgis, geoserver, raster

I am using Opengeo Suite 3.0.2, PostGIS 2.0.3 and PostgreSQl 9.2.

I am trying to import raster data from PostGIS to Geoserver but facing an error.

I follow this tutorial link to import the raster data from PostGIS.

http://dev.horizon.opengeo.org/opengeo-docs/geoserver/tutorials/imagemosaic-jdbc/imagemosaic-jdbc_tutorial.html

All steps are going good.

I used **FWtools 2.2.4** to make tiles. 
**gdal_retile** works fine.

These are my XML configuration files...

**rasterdata.pgraster.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?> 
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [ <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping" "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc"> 
<!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect" "connect.pgraster.xml.inc"> ]> 
<config version="1.0"> 
<coverageName name="slp"/> 
<coordsys name="EPSG:4326"/> 
<scaleop interpolation="1"/> &mapping; &connect; 
</config>
```

**connect.pgraster.xml.inc**

```
<connect>
<dstype value="DBCP"/> 
<username value="postgres" /> 
<password value="postgre" /> 
<jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/spatial_db" /> 
<driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/> 
<maxActive value="10"/> 
<maxIdle value="0"/> 
</connect>
```

**mapping.pgraster.xml.inc**

```
<spatialExtension name="postgis"/>
<mapping> 
<masterTable name="rasterdata_master2" > 
  <coverageNameAttribute name="slp"/> 
  <maxXAttribute name="maxx"/> 
  <maxYAttribute name="maxy"/> 
  <minXAttribute name="minx"/> 
  <minYAttribute name="miny"/> 
  <resXAttribute name="resx"/> 
  <resYAttribute name="resy"/> 
  <tileTableNameAtribute name="TileTable" /> 
  <spatialTableNameAtribute name="SpatialTable" />
</masterTable> 
<tileTable> 
  <blobAttributeName name="rast" /> 
  <keyAttributeName name="rid" /> 
</tileTable> 
<spatialTable>
  <keyAttributeName name="rid" />
  <geomAttributeName name="geom" />
  <tileMaxXAttribute name="maxX"/>
  <tileMaxYAttribute name="maxY"/>
  <tileMinXAttribute name="minX"/>
  <tileMinYAttribute name="minY"/>
</spatialTable>
</mapping>
```

After that I used the DDL generation utility which creates 4 Sql Scripts.

I execute the required script which creates the metadata tables.

now I used java utility to import the image data. That also works fine.

But when I try to use the image mosaic jdbc plugin to import the raster data through jdbc database, it gives an error, i.e.  **"Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Argument "value" should not be null."**

I am not able to insert the screenshot right now, so can't show you the screenshot of error.

Thanks

Akhil

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the same as in [How to publish PostGIS Rasters in Geoserver?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37451/how-to-publish-postgis-rasters-in-geoserver):
Following the [configuration instructions](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html) for the PostGIS raster plugin, you should try replacing

```
<spatialExtension name="postgis"/>
```

with

```
<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
```

in configration file `mapping.postgis.xml.inc`.

Also, maybe `<password value="postgre" />` in **connect.pgraster.xml.inc** is a typo for `<password value="postgres" />`.