# Show raster data in WEB

Tags: raster, postgresql, data, web

I have downloaded Landsat8 image and use matlab to processing temperature and vegetation. Then I insert data into PostGIS.
I used QGIS to display the results but i want show in web. How to display the Web ? Help me . I use postgresql to store data from raster image Lansat8
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a map server to publish postGIS data.
I could advise you [geoserver](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/#) and in particular [Postgis Raster Plug in](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/library/coverage/pgraster.html).

you can find some technical help [Here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37451/how-to-publish-postgis-rasters-in-geoserver)

Comment: You're welcome... hope help you