# How to set schema on GeoServer ImageMosaic JDBC?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, image-mosaic

I've publish raster from postgis to geoserver with ImageMosaic JDBC like explained on [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37451/publishing-postgis-rasters-in-geoserver) and it work properly on the default 'public' schema.

But how to set a custom schema ?

Answer (score 0):

As described in the [manual](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/raster/imagemosaic/configuration.html#datastore-properties) you can add `schema=my_schema` to the `datastore.properties` file.

Comment: I use ImageMosaic JDBC plugin, like describe in my post. So I've three files : connect.pgraster.xml.inc, mapping.pgraster.xml.inc and oek.pgraster.xml, not datastore.properties. Maybe I can add it and it may be work, but how ?