# Publishing raster from PostGIS with GeoServer

Tags: raster, postgis, geoserver, docker

Goal: Publish rasters stored in columns of PostGIS DB using GeoServer

GeoServer-version is **2.19.0** run inside a docker-container

I found the *Image Mosaic JDBC*-Extension and followed this post: [Publishing PostGIS Rasters in GeoServer?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37451/publishing-postgis-rasters-in-geoserver)
but it is not working.

The error I get is this:

> Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:/usr/local/tomcat/data/coverages/oek.pgraster.xml and hints Hints: REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@1dbbadd EXECUTOR_SERVICE = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6043eebf[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0] System defaults: FILTER_FACTORY = FilterFactoryImpl LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT = true GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY = GridCoverageFactory TILE_ENCODING = null STYLE_FACTORY = StyleFactoryImpl COMPARISON_TOLERANCE = 1.0E-8 FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING = http FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true FEATURE_FACTORY = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@3b44827c

Here are my files:

oek.pgraster.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE ImageMosaicJDBCConfig [
  <!ENTITY mapping PUBLIC "mapping"  "mapping.pgraster.xml.inc">
  <!ENTITY connect PUBLIC "connect"  "connect.postgis.xml.inc">
]>

<config version="1.0">
  <coverageName name="oek"/>
  <coordsys name="EPSG:25832"/>
  <!-- interpolation 1 = nearest neighbour, 2 = bipolar, 3 = bicubic -->
  <scaleop  interpolation="1"/>
<axisOrder ignore="false"/>
  &mapping;
  &connect;
</config>
```

mapping.pgraster.xml.inc:

```
<spatialExtension name="pgraster"/>
<mapping>
    <masterTable name="sentinel_2" >
        <coverageNameAttribute name="name"/>
        <x_swAttribute name="x_sw"/>
        <y_swAttribute name="y_sw"/>
        <b01Attribute name="b01"/>
        <b02_b03_b04_b08_mskAttribute name="b02_b03_b04_b08_msk"/>
        <b05_b06_b07_b8a_b11_b12_mskAttribute name="b05_b06_b07_b8a_b11_b12_msk"/>
        <sensing_dateAttribute name="sensing_date"/>
        <coregisteredAttribute name="coregistered"/>
        <s2_sensorAttribute name="s2_sensor"/>
        <s2_levelAttribute name="s2_level"/>
        <cloud_coverAttribute name="cloud_cover"/>
    </masterTable>
</mapping>
```

connect.postgis.xml.inc: (I replaced the user, password and host-IP)

```
<connect>
  <dstype value="DBCP"/>
  <username value="user" />
  <password value="password"/>
  <jdbcUrl value="jdbc:postgresql:HOST:PORT/ts_data"/>
  <driverClassName value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
  <maxActive value="10"/>
  <maxIdle value="0"/>
</connect>
```

Logfiles:

> 2022-07-14 09:11:04,169 WARN [jdbc.datasource] - Could not acquire A BDCP connection pool.:org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Connection pool improperly set up: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
> org.geotools.data.DataSourceException: Connection pool improperly set up: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.)
> at org.geotools.data.jdbc.datasource.DBCPDataSourceFactory.createNewDataSource(DBCPDataSourceFactory.java:107)
> at (......)
> 2022-07-14 09:11:04,195 INFO [geoserver.web] - Getting list of coverages for saved store file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/coverages/oek.pgraster.xml
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not list layers for this store, an error occurred retrieving them: Failed to create reader from file:/opt/geoserver/data_dir/coverages/oek.pgraster.xml and hints Hints:
> REPOSITORY = org.geoserver.catalog.CatalogRepository@4eaa0b54
> System defaults:
> FILTER_FACTORY                   = FilterFactoryImpl
> LENIENT_DATUM_SHIFT              = true
> GRID_COVERAGE_FACTORY            = GridCoverageFactory
> TILE_ENCODING                  = null
> STYLE_FACTORY                    = StyleFactoryImpl
> COMPARISON_TOLERANCE             = 1.0E-8
> FORCE_AXIS_ORDER_HONORING        = http
> FORCE_LONGITUDE_FIRST_AXIS_ORDER = true
> FEATURE_FACTORY                  = org.geotools.feature.LenientFeatureFactoryImpl@3b44827c
> EXECUTOR_SERVICE                 = java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@6043eebf[Running, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]

Comment: You need to turn up the logging level to developer in the global settings page, and then make the request again. Then [edit] your question with the **relevant** part of the log file.

Comment: I added the logfiles, apparently the BDCP-connection tries to check localhost:5432 for the DB even though I configured it diffently in my connect.postgis.xml file.

Comment: My GeoServer-Container is running on the same host-machine as my DB now, still not able to connect. I changed the host:IP to //localhost:5432 in my connect-file. Any hints/directions @IanTurton?